# can't add list elements to a dict in python except the last one

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, python-requests

i have a list of dict that i wnat to convert them to one dict but the problem is when i use the loop to add them only the last one get added
note that the Reaquest returns a list of json objects that i want to convert to python dic.

```
 import json

 import requests
 my_requset = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")


request_parse = my_requset.json()


new_dcit = {}

for i in request_parse:
    new_dcit.update(i)

for key , val in new_dcit.items():
     print(key ," : ", val)
```

if there is any other way to convert a json objects to dic please share it

Comment: Each of the dicts in your JSON data has exactly the same set of keys.  If you merge them all into a single dict with `.update()`, then of course each one will entirely overwrite the previous one.  What is your desired result here?

Comment: i wnat to be able to access each dict just like when you convert a json to javascrip it still gives you all the  objects inside the list  even if the keys are the same

Comment: Probable [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Your original question, and subsequent comment, are unclear about the desired behavior. It might help if you provided an example of the input and expected result.

Comment: Note that *request_parse* **is** a list of Python dictionaries. Not sure what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The new_dict.update(i) is just replacing the current data.

If you want to preserve them, keep them in a list of dictionary, so my_requset.json(). Or assign a unique key as you go through each data in request_parse.

For example:

```
request_parse = my_requset.json()


new_dcit = {}

for i in request_parse:
    new_dict[i[id]] = i # I used id as the unique key

print(new_dict[2])
```

Result

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette"
    ...
}
```